# ActiveRecord OR query behavior when first argument is nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

There is a record with `foo=nil` and `bar=43`. Why does the following query does not match that record. Should it not just check only `foo` since it matches with the given value (i.e `nil`)?

```
myrecords.where("foo = ? OR bar = ?", nil, 42).first
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can try this way null value is not compare in mysql for more info of `NULL` values refer
[Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

```
myrecords.where("foo is null OR bar = ?", 42).first
```

> If in case you are not aware of value of object is `null` or
>   `not null` used  [NULL-safe equal to operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)  of mysql as:

```
 myrecords.where("foo <=> ? OR bar = ?", nil, 42).first
```

Comment: This works if I know the value is null. But if the code was `myrecords.where("foo = ? OR bar = ?", some_obj_could_be_nil, 42).first`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks! I wish there was a database independent solution in rails

Comment: @balki in higher version of rails you can place `OR` condition in rails active record query or `Arel` query you can place `OR` then you can directly create active record query. then their is no database dependent part.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
myrecords.where("foo = ? OR bar = ?", NULL, 42).first
```

Comment: hey `where(foo: nil, bar: 42)` is this place `OR` clause?? i think it place `AND` in mysql query. and OP requires `OR`

Comment: What is NULL? a constant defined somewhere? Is the issue mysql specific. The behaviour could be different elsewhere?

Comment: True, that's why I had the second solution (which I removed because it creates AND query). Just write a Unit test to confirm it works in your current setup. Or use a gem which is capable of performing OR queries. I think MetaWhere does this.

Comment: PS. it looks like Rails 5 will be supporting the use of the .or method to chain multiple .where's, but that probably won't help you at this moment.